# regex pattern to get data from html

Tags: regex, preg-match

I need to get 19 from below string using `preg_match`.

Please advice!

```
LMS.pageData['product']['price']['value'] = '19';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match:

```
\['price'\]\['value'\] = '([\d.]*)'
```

And extract `$1`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cD2rD8/14)